# Bootstrap header is not visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which contains several fields and a header imported. The problem is on this page, the header and first field are not visible depending on the screen size. How can I fix the code?
I am not familiar with HTML and CSS. Could you explain me what is the problem? Maybe the problem is in the HTML structure?

This the page :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="icon" href="">
 <title>My page</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="test">
  <div id="">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="ressources/my_logo.png" width="85" height="50" alt="Logo">
      MY HEADER
    </a>
      </div>
</nav>
  </div>
  <form method="post" action="requetes/creerUtilisateur.php" role="form" id="formulaireUtiisateur" >
   <h4>Créer un nouvel utilisateur :</h4>
   <hr>
   <input class="form-control" id="identifiant_camion" name="identifiant_camion" type="text" placeholder="Identifiant camion" required>
   <hr>
   <label for="type_chauffeur">Type de chauffeur</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="type_chauffeur" name="type_chauffeur">
    <option>Type 1</option>
    <option>Type 1</option>
    <option>Type 1</option>
   </select>
   <hr>
   <input class="form-control" id="prenom_chauffeur" name="prenom_chauffeur" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" required>
   <hr>
   <input class="form-control" id="nom_chauffeur" name="nom_chauffeur" type="text" placeholder="Nom" required>
   <hr>
   <input class="form-control" id="mot_de_passe" name="mot_de_passe" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
   <hr>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="creer_utilisateur" type="submit">Créer utilisateur</button>
  </form>

  <form method="post" action="requetes/creerAnnonce.php" role="form" id="formulaireAnnonce">
   <hr>
   <h4>Diffuser une annonce aux utilisateurs:</h4>
   <hr>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="type_annonce">Type de l'annonce</label>
    <select class="form-control type_annonce" id="type_annonce" name="type_annonce">
     <option>Type 1</option>
     <option>Type 2</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <label for="destinataire">Destinataire</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="destinataire" name="destinataire">
     <option>Chauffeurs 1</option>
     <option>Chauffeurs 2</option>
     <option>user1</option>    </select>
    <label for="annonce">Diffuser une annonce aux utilisateurs</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="annonce" name="annonce" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="creer_annonce" type="submit">Diffuser l'annonce</button>
  </form>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I examined the codes. I think it looks like there are problems with the opening and closing tags. No need to use extra row in navbar. Due to its structure, Bootstrap already offers the necessary css adjustments ready. I also recommend you to separate both navbar and form elements. I hope your problem is resolved now. Otherwise I will have to see the css files.

```
 <div id="_navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="ressources/my_logo.png" width="85" height="50" alt="Logo">
                MY HEADER
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>



<div id="form-elements">

    <form method="post" action="requetes/creerUtilisateur.php" role="form" id="formulaireUtiisateur">
        <h4>Créer un nouvel utilisateur :</h4>
        <hr>
        <input class="form-control" id="identifiant_camion" name="identifiant_camion" type="text"
            placeholder="Identifiant camion" required>
        <hr>
        <label for="type_chauffeur">Type de chauffeur</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="type_chauffeur" name="type_chauffeur">
            <option>Type 1</option>
            <option>Type 1</option>
            <option>Type 1</option>
        </select>
        <hr>
        <input class="form-control" id="prenom_chauffeur" name="prenom_chauffeur" type="text" placeholder="Prénom"
            required>
        <hr>
        <input class="form-control" id="nom_chauffeur" name="nom_chauffeur" type="text" placeholder="Nom" required>
        <hr>
        <input class="form-control" id="mot_de_passe" name="mot_de_passe" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"
            required>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="creer_utilisateur" type="submit">Créer utilisateur</button>
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="requetes/creerAnnonce.php" role="form" id="formulaireAnnonce">
        <hr>
        <h4>Diffuser une annonce aux utilisateurs:</h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type_annonce">Type de l'annonce</label>
            <select class="form-control type_annonce" id="type_annonce" name="type_annonce">
                <option>Type 1</option>
                <option>Type 2</option>
            </select>
            <hr>
            <label for="destinataire">Destinataire</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="destinataire" name="destinataire">
                <option>Chauffeurs 1</option>
                <option>Chauffeurs 2</option>
                <option>user1</option>
            </select>
            <label for="annonce">Diffuser une annonce aux utilisateurs</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="annonce" name="annonce" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="creer_annonce" type="submit">Diffuser l'annonce</button>
    </form>

</div>
```